# How to convert a mydumper's table.sql file with insert statement and table-schema.sql file to CSVs

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

I am using mydumper to dump the db. Since there is not support to generate csv output from mydumper I need to do that from a shell script.

Mydumper generates 2 files one with data and other with schema. However they are in .sql.gz form so I converted them to .sql first and now trying to convert them to csv.

A sample dump file of table platform looks like

platforms.sql :

```
/*!40101 SET NAMES binary*/;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0*/;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
INSERT INTO `platforms` VALUES
(4,"DSV","DSV"),
(5,"IPTV","IPTV"),
(6,"Mobile","MOBILE"),
(7,"Portable","PORTABLE"),
(8,"VOD","VOD"),
(9,"DVR","DVR"),
(10,"Broadband","BROADBAND"),
(11,"Zodiac","ZODIAC"),
(12,"EPG","EPG"),
(13,"IP Linear","IPLINEAR"),
(14,"Addressable Linear","ADDRESSABLE_LINEAR");
```

pltforms-schema.sql :

```
/*!40101 SET NAMES binary*/;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0*/;

/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
CREATE TABLE `platforms` (
  `platform_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `platform_name` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `external_ref` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`platform_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `platform_id` (`platform_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `external_ref` (`external_ref`),
  UNIQUE KEY `platform_name_uni` (`platform_name`),
  KEY `AI_platform_id` (`platform_id`),
  KEY `external_ref_2` (`external_ref`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=15 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Now I need the platforms.csv and platforms.csv from these files which I can use further for my processing.

For platforms.csv it should look like :

```
"4","DSV","DSV"
"5","IPTV","IPTV"
"6","Mobile","MOBILE"
"7","Portable","PORTABLE"
"8","VOD","VOD"
"9","DVR","DVR"
"10","Broadband","BROADBAND"
"11","Zodiac","ZODIAC"
"12","EPG","EPG"
"13","IP Linear","IPLINEAR"
"14","Addressable Linear","ADDRESSABLE_LINEAR"
```

For platforms-schema.csv it should look like :

```
platforms,platform_id:int(11),platform_name:varchar(150),external_ref:varchar(40)
```

It will be great if someone can help me in this.

Comment: Use `SELECT .. INTO OUTFILE` instead of dumper for to obtain CSV file with table's data.

Comment: @Akina didn't get that. I need to write a script for conversion. So that I can run it for all tables in the db.

Comment: *I need to write a script for conversion.* What a problem? skip leading lines, remove leading/trailing parenthesis and trailing commas/semicolon, save the rest to output file.

Comment: With sed -n '/^INSERT/p'  I am only getting INSERT INTO `platforms` VALUES seems there is an enter at the end of the line. I manually checked it on https://sed.js.org/ . How to get the remove that?

Comment: Also what to do for schema CSV. How to generate that?

Comment: Schema cannot be represented as CSV adequately.

Comment: But I need to dump the schema in platforms,platform_id:int(11),platform_name:varchar(150),external_ref:varchar(40) form for further processing.